# Can I use the same Tenant ID for two applications?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I have two different applications one with with Azure AD implementation existing on prod and another one which we are transitioning from traditional login to Azure AD. Is it possible to use the same Tenant ID of the application which is in prod for the new implementation as well for running a round of dev testing before registering the new application on Azure AD for a new set of IDs.

Comment: As long as any security groups that you need are there, sure. You don't state what kind of app, but if a c# website, you can add as many redirect uris as you want, including localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you want to say "use the same **Client ID** of the application" rather than **Tenant ID** right?

Yes. Of course you can use the same Azure AD app for testing purpose. Just specify a different reply URL for the new application.

But when the new application is moving into production environment, it's recommended to use a new Azure AD application because it's convenient to control permissions and roles for the user.

Answer (score 0):

"Tenant ID of the application" - You mean Client ID. Yes you can use the Same Azure AD App with the same Client multiple purpose provide it has necessary scope of permission to help you with the testing.